# What is the purpose of the view() method in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

**Code 1**

```
arr = np.array([1, 2, 3])
arr2 = arr.view()
```

**Code 2**

```
arr = np.array([1, 2, 3])
arr2 = arr
```

Both of these snippets have the same functionality, so why do we actually need the `view` method in NumPy if we can simply achieve the same result with code 2?

Comment: `view()` is rarely used without an argument.   And the `arr2=arr` action (or lack thereof) often gives problems to new users of Python.

Answer (score 3):

Even without using the things `view` lets you do, the semantics are different.

```
arr2 = arr
```

This assigns a reference to the original array to a different name. Any change you make to `arr2` short of reassignment will show up when you access `arr`.

```
arr2 = arr.view()
```

This creates a new array object that only shares data with the original. You can do something like `arr2.shape = (3, 1, 1)` without affecting `arr` at all.

At the same time, that's not what `view` is generally used for. Let's say you wanted to look at the individual bytes that make up your integers. You would create a view with a different dtype:

```
arr2 = arr.view(np.uint8)
```

Or say you wanted to reinterpret your integers as big- instead of little-endian:

```
arr2 = arr.view('>i4')
```

Keep in mind that many other useful operations do this as well, like `reshape` (same dtype, different shape), `transpose` (same dtype, different strides), etc.

Answer (score 2):

As you can read in [`documentation`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.view.html):

> `a.view(some_dtype)` or `a.view(dtype=some_dtype)` constructs a view of the array’s memory with a different data-type. This can cause a reinterpretation of the bytes of memory.

So you can create an array with different types like below:

```
>>> arr = np.array([1,2,3])
>>> arr2 = arr.view(dtype=np.int8)
>>> arr2
array([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0], dtype=int8)

>>> arr2 = arr.view(dtype=np.int32)
array([1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0], dtype=int32)

#You can change type and dtype like below
>>> arr2 = arr.view(dtype=np.int64, type=np.matrix)
>>> arr2
matrix([[1, 2, 3]])
```

If you write like below `view` and `assign` like same:

```
>>> arr2 = arr.view(dtype=np.int64)
>>> arr2.dtype
dtype('int64')


>>> arr3 = arr
>>> arr3.dtype
dtype('int64')
```